# What is the condition for "transpose(A) x B = transpose(B) x A" to be true?

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product, transpose

I need help with some basic doubts in linear algebra.

Given two vectors of equal dimensions, A and B, it can be easily shown that "transpose(A) x B = transpose(B) x A".
What if A and B are higher-order tensors, say matrices? Is there a condition when "transpose(A) x B = transpose(B) x A" is true?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When $A^{T}B$ is symmetric.

Comment: Which is to say, hardly ever.